# Downloading Azure portal OS .vhd as a backup

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, backup, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure and cloud computing in general. I am about to resize my Linux VM OS disk using: 
Update-AzureDisk –DiskName "" -Label "ResiZedOS" -ResizedSizeInGB

But before that, I want to make sure that I don't lose my data for whatever reason. Therefore, I need a backup of my current OS Disk that I am about to expand.

Now, I read a little about the backup services provided by Azure. But can't I just download the OS .vhd file to my local computer and, if needed, upload back and reattach to the VM?

Am I getting this right? And if I am, could that be done while the VM is running?

The VM is classic deployed Ubuntu.

Comment: Why not just snapshot the disk, or copy it to another blob? Why the need to download locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your scenario, you could use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#blob-copy) to copy the VHD to another storage account. The data transfer between Azure data center, it cost you only a few minutes. You could use the backup VHD to recreate a new VM.

You could use the following commands.

```
AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1 /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2 /SourceKey:key /DestKey:key /Pattern:abc.txt
```

Example

```
AzCopy /Source:https://t5portalvhdsx2463gvmvrz7.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /Dest:https://61portalvhdsbkv71y4r29cs.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /SourceKey:VK8LDCaAudknX9LCGPlpemHzB9FXMKZBJxAY2i8YwWAtUWFti3PKW9iNnFvlGX0TN/csvPkUDbnL22cdro5LPQ== /DestKey:fWjwkegnh7lL84GJIpeAEaLaL5uh+upNXvI4tqgtUa8mw71cJuxv4W1vbzJtSabaj+Cg2E06OSUCIX1BmMH/jg== /Pattern:shui-shui-2017-02-02.vhd
```

You could get source key and dest key on Azure Portal.

[image]

You could download Azcopy from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#download-and-install-azcopy).

**Note:When you copy VHD, you should stop VM.**

Comment: Thank you. this is working. Would it matter if, instead of copying the .vhd to a new storage account, I would place it in the same storage account but different container?

Comment: Yes, it possible. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#blob-copy)`Copy single blob within Storage account`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply download VM's OS disk and then upload it back to Azure if something goes wrong. But you can't do this while VM is running. You will have to stop it first.

Comment: I see. This would take 18 hours to finish though given the size of the VM and the speed of my internet. Is there any other faster way? Like copying the OS Disk blob to a new storage account?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than downloading the whole VHD for backup purpose (which is very slow and needs to be done after shutting down the VM for data consistency), I'd suggest you to [snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/creating-a-snapshot-of-a-blob) the VHD blob since the operation can be done on a running VM and completed immediately.